# How to annotate a list that may or MAY NOT have different types?

Tags: python, list, type-hinting, python-typing, pylance

***python version: 3.10.2***

It was of my understanding that `list[str|int]` should allow three distinct types of values:

1. List of only strings (`list[str]`)
2. List of only ints (`list[int]`)
3. List of both strings and ints (`list[str|int]`)

Is this assumption right, or am I understanding it wrong ? because that's not what happens when I'm coding:

```
def test(x: list[str|int]):
    pass

# All fine
test([]); test(['a']); test([0]); test(['a', 0])

x: list[str] = []
y: list[int] = []
z: list[str|int] = []

test(x); test(y); test(z)
```

[image: Pylance complaining that list[str] and list[int] are not compatible with list[str|int]]

It accepts lists with only strings or only ints, but **only** if I don't specify that the list in question only accepts one of these values. `x` and `y` are explicitly declared as lists that only accepts **one** of this values (`int` or `str`), and because of that they are rejected. Is this really what is supposed to happen, or is it a bug ?

If I change the function annotation to accept a `Sequence[str|int]` instead of a `list[str|int]`, then everything is fine. And same for `Container[str|int]`, or even `tuple[str|int, ...]`
[[image: No errors displayed when parameter x of function test is declared to be Containerstr|int]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

The type checker doesn't know or care what `test` does with the list. It only cares about what it *might* do to the list. One thing that would be legal is to add a `str` to the list: you said that (the parameter) `x` has type `list[str|int]`. That's fine if the list passed to `test` has type `list[str|int]` or `list[str]`; it's *not* fine if the list has type `list[int]`.

That is, `test` does  not accept lists that have either `str` or `int` values: it accepts lists that *must* be able to contain `str` or `int` values.

The problem goes away when you change the type of the parameter to `Sequence[str|int]`, because a `Sequence` does not permit mutation. The type guarantees that if you provide a `list[int]` value, `test` won't try to *add* a `str` to the list.

Comment: Just a minor correction: both ``list[str]`` and ``list[int]`` are _"not fine"_. On the first image, both ``x`` and ``y`` show errors.

Comment: So, if I don't plan to add values, I can use ``Sequence``. And if I really need it to be a ``list``, the only way to get what I want is: ``x: list[str] | list[int] | list[str | int]`` ?

Comment: You can, but you still aren't going to be able to add, say, an `int` to `x` inside the function if there is a possibility it's a (statically typed) `list[str]`.

Comment: `list[str|int]` is probably fine as the *annotation*, but if you want to pass a value that was statically typed as `list[int]` or `list[str]`, you'll have to cast it, and then it's your responsibility to make sure that the function doesn't do anything to break your static guarantee that the list is homogenous.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense I guess. Because if I add a ``int``, inside the function, in a list declared as ``list[str]`` outside the function, it will be changed as well.

It's kinda dull, but makes sense at least... Thanks for the answer!

Comment: It's important to remember that static types are distinct from runtime types.

Comment: Yeah, I know this type hints are ignored at run time. My code was running exactly as I expected, but still, this warnings were annoying me. Especially because it felt like it should be all fine.

Comment: It's not just that type hints are ignored at run time. `x: list[str|int] = [1,2,3]` is very different for static typchecking purposes than `y: list[int] = [1,2,3]`.